# What is the difference between a "research plan" and a "research proposal"?

Tags: phd, research-proposal

Online sources often use "*research plan*" and "*research proposal*" interchangeably.

Two months after getting accepted into a PhD program, I was asked to do a research plan.  Is this the same as doing a research proposal?

Comment: What does your advisor say?

Comment: I would say, a research proposal is what you would do applying for a PhD position or for funding to explain what you want to do, a research plan is what you would do to show you know where you a going with your research.

Comment: Ask older students in your program. If it's a general requirement, then they must have done one as well, so they can tell you what to do.

Comment: Even confined to only one term, each of them can be interpreted differently by different institutions. The best bet and ask for a style/format guide from the department, or consult previous students' submissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither a research plan nor a research proposal is a "super specific thing you need to know about".

A proposal, on any subject, generally includes things like objectives, background, potential challenges, and a vague schedule.

A plan often includes all of the above, in greater detail, as well as necessary resources, a specific schedule with milestones, and perhaps additional project specific elements (e.g. which programming languages you might use).